# How is \mathbf defined?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

One would define \mathbf as say:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathbf}{OT1}{cmr12}{bx}{n}
```

I was wondering, then with that, how \mathbf would be defined? (what is its meaning?).

Comment: You should try `\def\pshow#1{{\let\protect\show #1}}
\pshow\mathbf`, as suggested by [The definitions of LaTeX commands](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=ltxcmds).

Comment: Sorry to bother you; in this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71393/3954 I proposed the use of the floatrow package, but then the OP mentioned an incompatibility with your `bidi` package. Is there a workaround to make the `floatrow` package cooperate with `bidi`?

Comment: Regarding the issue I mentioned in my previous comment, I found a workaround and included it in my answer (link in previous comment). Anyways, if you could take a look, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than looking straight at the code with `\meaning`, `\show`, `\tracingall` or the like it might be interesting to read the main articles on NFSS (the *then* New Font Selection Scheme). They are a bit aged now (1989 :-) ) so they predate LaTeX2e and even TeX3, but I think they will give you some ideas, especially the first one, on the underlying concepts. Be aware though that these papers describe the initial version of NFSS. For LaTeX2e some interfaces got changed and we further optimized the code for speed and compactness.

[NFSS base macros in Tugboat 1989](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-2/tb24mitt.pdf)

[NFSS user interface in Tugboat 1990](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb11-2/tb28mitt.pdf)

The current code (and its documentation) can be found as part of the LaTeX distribution, look for files called `ltfss`*something*`.dtx` and typeset them. They are fairly well documented (give or take) but the documentation mainly concerns the micro level not the big picture.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please have a look at this question of mine too: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61212/redefining-mathbf-without-using-a-new-math-alphabet

Answer (score 6):

Run the following through LaTeX

```
\makeatletter
\show\mathbf
\expandafter\show\csname mathbf \endcsname
\show\select@group
\expandafter\show\csname M@OT1\endcsname
\show\default@M
```

You'll get

```
> \mathbf=macro:
->\protect \mathbf  .

> \mathbf =macro:
->\select@group \mathbf  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/bx/n .

> \select@group=macro:
#1#2#3#4->\ifx \math@bgroup \bgroup \else \relax \expandafter \@firstofone \fi 
{\ifmmode \ifnum \csname c@mv@\math@version \endcsname <\sixt@@n \begingroup \e
scapechar \m@ne \getanddefine@fonts {\csname c@mv@\math@version \endcsname }#3\
globaldefs \@ne \math@fonts \endgroup \init@restore@version \xdef #1{\noexpand 
\use@mathgroup \noexpand #2{\number \csname c@mv@\math@version \endcsname }}\gl
obal \advance \csname c@mv@\math@version \endcsname \@ne \else \let #1\relax \@
latex@error {Too many math alphabets used in version \math@version }\@eha \fi \
else \expandafter \non@alpherr \fi #1{#4}}.

> \M@OT1=macro:
->\default@M .

> \default@M=macro:
->.
```

It's quite frightening, but not too much.

The bulk of course is `\select@group`, which must check whether the corresponding mathgroup (math family in TeXbook terminology) has already been allocated. Then essentially it opens a group, sets the mathgroup and typesets the argument, unless the command has been given outside of math mode.