# Is there a way to print two tikzpictures next to each other marked with a and b?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bidi

I have the following code that should print the two figures next to each other with an a to the left of the first figure and a b to the left of the second one. The code below does this, but everything is aligned to the bottom line. Is there an option to force the pictures down? Or maybe a totally different way of avhiving my goal? Thanks!

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}ll@{\hspace{2cm}}ll@{}}
a. & \begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree[.N 
          [.PV pazirāi ]
          [.N 
            [.V kon- ] ande ] ]
\end{tikzpicture} &
b. &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree[.N 
          [.V 
            [.PV pazirāi ]
            [.V kon- ] ] ande ] 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an option using the [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) and [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) packages; as an advantage of this approach, you don't have to manually label the figures and can easily control the vertical position of the labels; furthermore, you can cross-reference the subfigures:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}

\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=center}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\sidesubfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree[.N 
          [.PV pazirāi ]
          [.N 
            [.V kon- ] ande ] ]
\end{tikzpicture} 
}\qquad%
\sidesubfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree[.N 
          [.V 
            [.PV pazirāi ]
            [.V kon- ] ] ande ] 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Simply loading the bidi package in the above solution (and processing with XeLaTeX), as in the following document:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{bidi}

\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=center}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\sidesubfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree[.N 
          [.PV pazirāi ]
          [.N 
            [.V kon- ] ande ] ]
\end{tikzpicture} 
}\qquad%
\sidesubfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree[.N 
          [.V 
            [.PV pazirāi ]
            [.V kon- ] ] ande ] 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

produces the error

```
! LaTeX Error: \floatc@plain undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.16 \renewcommand\floatc@plain
                               [2]{\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{\@fs@cfont #1:} #2}%

?
```

A workaround then is to define `\floatc@plain` *before* loading the `bidi` package; the definition can be found in the `float.sty` file; the following code can be processed without errors and produces the desired result:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\floatc@plain[2]{\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{\@fs@cfont #1:} #2}%
  \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\hsize {\@fs@cfont #1:} #2\par
    \else\hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}\fi}
\makeatother
\usepackage{bidi}

\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=center}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\sidesubfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree[.N 
          [.PV pazirāi ]
          [.N 
            [.V kon- ] ande ] ]
\end{tikzpicture} 
}\qquad%
\sidesubfloat[]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree[.N 
          [.V 
            [.PV pazirāi ]
            [.V kon- ] ] ande ] 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would prefer this solution, but it seems incompatible with the `bidi` package:  (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bidi/xcolor-xetex-bidi.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bidi/float-xetex-bidi.def

! LaTeX Error: \floatc@plain undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.16 \renewcommand\floatc@plain
                               [2]{\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{\@fs@cfont #1:} #2}%

?

Comment: @StefanMüller true. The author of `bidi` claims compatibility with `subfig` but says nothing about `floatrow`; perhaps you could contact him about this issue (he is one of the regulars here).

Comment: When I started to deal with Persian, I tried to email him, but his mail account is not functional. Maybe he reads this. I try adding the bidi tag to my question ...

Comment: @StefanMüller I left a note for the author about this particular issue; let's hope the note reaches him.

Comment: @StefanMüller In the meantime I've found a solution to the `floatrow-bidi` problem; Please see my updated answer and  let me know if it produces the desired result.

Comment: Yes, works! Thanks! How are such cases handled? Will this be taken care of in `bidi` later? Will it be anounced here later or do I have to check the updates and test whether I can remove your additional code?

Comment: @StefanMüller Glad to hear it worked. Regarding your question, I guess we have to wait and see if the package author receives my note (I provided a link to your question and my answer) and see what he decides to do.

Comment: Make a bug report in https://github.com/vafa/bidi/issues  but I do not promise updating bidi package unless there is some donations to the project

Answer (score 7):

The following example shows two methods to shift the `tikz` pictures. The first is using `\raisebox{-.5\height}{...}` that would also work with images. Then second uses a option `baseline`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}ll@{\hspace{2cm}}ll@{}}
a. & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree[.N
          [.PV pazirai ]
          [.N
            [.V kon- ] ande ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}} &
b. &
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\Tree[.N
          [.V
            [.PV pazirai ]
            [.V kon- ] ] ande ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

You can also use one TikZ picture and the `local bounding box` options but I would recommend using the [`subcaption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subcaption) package to handle your subfigures properly. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=aa]
\Tree[.N 
          [.PV pazirāi ]
          [.N 
            [.V kon- ] ande ] ]

\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(6,0)},local bounding box=bb]
\Tree[.N 
          [.V 
            [.PV pazirāi ]
            [.V kon- ] ] ande ] 

\end{scope}

\node[right = -1cm of aa.west] {a.)};
\node[right = -1cm of bb.west] {b.)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

It might need additional shifts if the scope heights are different.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This solution doesn't give the format you requested, but it uses the [`subcaption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subcaption) to give `(a)` and `(b)` below each `subfigure`. Note that a lot of people reading your document will expect to see the captions *below* the figures, and won't necessarily be looking for them to the side.

[image]

Using this approach is somewhat advantageous because you can reference them easily using the standard `label` and `ref` techniques.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \Tree[.N 
            [.PV pazirāi ]
            [.N 
            [.V kon- ] ande ] ]
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        \caption{First subpicture}
        \label{fig:myfirstsubfig}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \Tree[.N 
            [.V 
            [.PV pazirāi ]
            [.V kon- ] ] ande ] 
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Second subpicture}
        \label{fig:mysecondsubfig}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option for manual labeling is too put the figures into minipages.  I use this technique to align all kind of figures, especially when the baseline of the figure can not be controlled (which is possible for TikZ figures though).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\my@figbox}
\newcommand{\myfigbox}[2][\empty]{
  \if#1\empty\else\textbf{#1}\fi%
  \savebox{\my@figbox}{#2}%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{\wd\my@figbox}
    \centering\vspace{0pt}
    \usebox{\my@figbox}%
  \end{minipage}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\myfigbox[a.]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \Tree[.N 
          [.PV pazirai ]
          [.N 
            [.V kon- ] ande ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\myfigbox[b.]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree[.N 
          [.V 
            [.PV pazirai ]
            [.V kon- ] ] ande ] 
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Often space can be saved by laying the labels over the figure.  For this one can modify the `\myfigbox` macro as follows:

```
\newcommand{\myfigbox}[2][\empty]{
  \if#1\empty\else\makebox[0pt][l]{\textbf{#1}}\fi%
  \savebox{\my@figbox}{#2}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\wd\my@figbox}
    \centering\vspace{0pt}
    \usebox{\my@figbox}%
  \end{minipage}%
}
```

which yields

[image]